# CSS all style gets applied with transition on page load

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I have a little bit of code to animate a button when hovered, but when i reload my page the css gets applied with the 1s transition i have set on  the button and button text.

I set the transition to only work on width of the button, this worked but if i want to animate multiple things i have to select to only animate those ones, which is kinda annoying seeing as i haven't had this problem before.

I am using Chrome 72.0.3626.122 on a Chromebook

```css
html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

body,
span {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.button {
 width: 120px;
 height: 40px;
 border: none;
 background-color: salmon;
 transition: 1s ease;
}

.button:hover {
 width: 200px;
}

.button-text {
 color: white;
 font-size: 17px;
 transition: 1s ease;
}

.button:hover .button-text {
 color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Button hover</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <button class="button">
  <span class="button-text">Hover me</span>
 </button>
</body>
</html>
```

This applies all css in 1 second after page reload, instead of loading all css instantly and transitioning on hover

Comment: Loads and looks fine to me

Comment: @StefanBob It works when i try the snippet but when i reload my browser on my own page it doesnt work

Answer (score -1):

> This applies all css in 1 second after page reload, instead of loading all css instantly and transitioning on hover

So you want the button to get wider and text darker automatically 1 second after the page loads, correct?

CSS animations should help you out here because they are self-invoking, whereas CSS transitions need a triggering event.

```
// Call the keyframes
.button { animation: expand 0.55s linear 2s 1 normal forwards running; }
.button-text { animation: color-shift 0.55s linear 2s 1 normal forwards running; }

// Keyframes
@keyframes expand {
    0% { width: 120px; }
    100% { width: 200px; }
}

@keyframes color-shift {
    0% { color: white; }
    100% { color: lightgray; }
}
```

I've used your HTML and CSS to show the difference [in this CodePen](https://codepen.io/code-and-pixels/pen/ZZePLZ), with some extra details. Hope that helps.